# Find one or few centroids in matrix produced by "all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length"

Tags: python, graph, centroid

Does there exist a realization of function in python that operates on matrix of "all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length"(shortest paths) and gives centroids of clusters of graph represented by the matrix.

Even better would be if you could give one that gives centroids by running on dictionary, which is a result of this function:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length